# Optimising the creation of convex hulls for multiple features in the same sf object

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, r-sf, convex-hull

I have a for loop that creates a convex hull for each sf points feature and corrects a couple of issues that occur when running it with my real data. However, I don't think it's overly efficient (my real data has thousands of features) and wondered if a non-for loop alternative may be quicker. I have looked at `purrr:map` as an alternative, but I am not sure how to implement my current solution using it.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(concaveman)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-I4F2NYvFWkNqy7ASFNxnyrwr_wT0lGF" , destfile="ProximityAreas.zip")
unzip("ProximityAreas.zip")
Proximity_Areas <- st_read("Proximity_Areas.gpkg") 

# this recreates my real data
Proximity_Areas_Points <- Proximity_Areas %>% st_cast("POINT")

Unique_UID_Codes <- unique(Proximity_Areas$UID)

Proximity_Convex  <- NULL

for (n in 1:nrow(Proximity_Areas)){

    # subsets only points for the loops gss code
    Points <- Proximity_Areas_Points %>% filter(UID %in% Unique_UID_Codes[n])
    
    # creates a convex hull and ensures valid geometry
    Loop_Convex <- st_make_valid(concaveman(Points, concavity = 1, length_threshold = 0))
    
    # some convex hulls extend beyond the extent of the original feature, this clips those parts off
    Loop_Convex_Clip <- st_intersection(Loop_Convex, Proximity_Areas %>% filter(UID %in% Unique_UID_Codes[n])) %>% 
        select(UID)
    
    # extracts convex hulls are geometry collection to polygons
    if (st_geometry_type(Loop_Convex_Clip) == "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION"){
    Loop_Convex_Clip <- st_collection_extract(Loop_Convex_Clip, "POLYGON") %>%
        group_by(UID) %>% 
        summarize(polygons = st_union(polygons)) %>%
        ungroup()}
        
    # if convex hull outputs point, linestring or multilinestring a buffer is used to make it a polygon
    if (!(st_geometry_type(Loop_Convex_Clip) %in% c("POLYGON", "MULTIPOLYGON"))){
        Style <- if_else(st_geometry_type(Loop_Convex_Clip)== "POINT", "SQUARE", "FLAT")
        Loop_Convex_Clip <- st_buffer(Loop_Convex_Clip, 12.5, endCapStyle=Style) %>%
            st_cast(., "MULTIPOLYGON") %>%
            st_intersection(., Proximity_Areas %>% filter(UID %in% Unique_UID_Codes[n])) %>% 
            select(UID)
        rm(Style)}
        
    # ensures geometry type of convex hulls are multipolygons
    if (st_geometry_type(Loop_Convex_Clip) == "POLYGON"){
    Loop_Convex_Clip <- st_cast(Loop_Convex_Clip, "MULTIPOLYGON")}
    
    # steps above can make convex hull geometry invalid, this fixes this issue 
    if(st_is_valid(Loop_Convex_Clip) == FALSE){
    Loop_Convex_Clip <- st_make_valid(Loop_Convex_Clip)}

    # adds loop outputs to sf object
    Proximity_Convex <- bind_rows(Proximity_Convex, Loop_Convex_Clip)
    
    # remove objects created during the loop
    rm(Points)
    rm(Loop_Convex)
    rm(Loop_Convex_Clip)
}
```